# My First Android App Does Not Run In Mobile

Tags: android

i have prepared my first android app in android studio, but it run only in Android Studio Emulator not in mobile. Please help me by telling the simple solution so that i can distribute the app to others.
Thank You.

Comment: "_does not run_" does not give any information for anyone to help you, specifically, what is the error when running on an actual device? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first to form your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "build" tab in the android studio and then click on "build apk". After your android studio is finished building the apk, you will have an option to go to the folder where the apk is located. Go to that folder, select the .apk file and transfer it to your phone. After, make sure that your android phone has a permission to install apps outside of PlayStore. Install your app!

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create an `.apk` of your app through studio. If it successfully runs in Emulator, that is a good sign. Once the `.apk` is created. Save it to Desktop or wherever else you would like. Plug in your android device and open the device in File Explorer (or equiv. depends on OS). Copy the `.apk` to your device's Downloads folder. Once the copy is successful, eject your device from your computer. Open the file manager (whatever it is called, I don't personally own an Android, but I had to fix my cousin's :p) on your device. Go to Downloads and click the `.apk` you just transferred to the device. A dialog should come up asking if you would like to install the app. Click yes, or install, or the equivalent. Go to your Apps view and it should be there.